# How can I instantiate a generic array type in java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, multidimensional-array, instantiation

I have a problem with instantiating a generic type array, here is my code:

```
public final class MatrixOperations<T extends Number>
{
    /**
 * <p>This method gets the transpose of any matrix passed in to it as argument</p>
 * @param matrix This is the matrix to be transposed
 * @param rows  The number of rows in this matrix
 * @param cols  The number of columns in this matrix
 * @return The transpose of the matrix
 */
public T[][] getTranspose(T[][] matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    T[][] transpose = new T[rows][cols];//Error: generic array creation
    for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            transpose[x][y] = matrix[y][x];
        }
    }
    return transpose;
}
}
```

I just want this method to be able to transpose a matrix that it's class is a subtype of Number and return the transpose of the matrix in the specified type. Anybody's help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Generics and arrays don't get along very well, as a general rule.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: true, but that's not a problem in this particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `java.lang.reflect.Array` to dynamically instantiate an Array of a given type. You just have to pass in the Class object of that desired type, something like this:

```
public T[][] getTranspose(Class<T> arrayType, T[][] matrix, int rows, int cols)
{

    T[][] transpose = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(arrayType, rows,cols);
    for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            transpose[x][y] = matrix[y][x];
        }
    }
    return transpose;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    MatrixOperations<Integer> mo = new MatrixOperations<>();
    Integer[][] i = mo.getTranspose(Integer.class, new Integer[2][2], 2, 2);
    i[1][1] = new Integer(13);  
}
```

Comment: The `arrayType` is not necessary, since it can be gotten from `matrix`.

Answer (score 5):

The type is not know at runtime, so you can't use it this way. Instead you need to something like.

```
Class type = matrix.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType();
T[][] transpose = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(type, rows, cols);
```

Note: generics cannot be primitives so you won't be able to use `double[][]`

Thank you @newacct for suggesting you allocate in one step.

Comment: note that you can allocate multidimensional arrays in one step with `Array.newInstance` as well

Comment: I get incompatible types when I do the first line. `matrix.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType();` returns a `Class<capture<?>>`, not a Class<T>.

Comment: @MatthewDrill true, the previous expression only works when the type is known at compile time. I have made it a raw type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to create both dimensions at once:

```
    // this is really a Class<? extends T> but the compiler can't verify that ...
    final Class<?> tClass = matrix.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType();
    // ... so this contains an unchecked cast.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[][] transpose = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(tClass, cols, rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Can I create an array whose component type is a wildcard parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20wildcard%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?) and [Can I create an array whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?)  from the Generics FAQ for a detailed explanation as to why you cannot do this.